# How to set and retrieve cookie in HTTP header in Python?

Tags: python, cookies, http-headers

I need to get the cookies from a HTTP response sent by a server and put it in the next request's header. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use the [cookielib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) with urllib.

It will store cookies between requests, and you can load/save them on disk.  Here is an example:

```
import cookielib
import urllib2

cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
handlers = [
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPSHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
    ]
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)

def fetch(uri):
    req = urllib2.Request(uri)
    return opener.open(req)

def dump():
    for cookie in cookies:
        print cookie.name, cookie.value

uri = 'http://www.google.com/'
res = fetch(uri)
dump()

res = fetch(uri)
dump()

# save cookies to disk. you can load them with cookies.load() as well.
cookies.save('mycookies.txt')
```

Notice that the values for `NID` and `PREF` are the same between requests.  If you omitted the `HTTPCookieProcessor` these would be different (urllib2 wouldn't send `Cookie` headers on the 2nd request).

Comment: build_opener() will add HTTPHandler for you. It will also add HTTPSHandler if the Python installation has SSL support. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener

Comment: hello i cant find a module named cookielib

Answer (score 15):

Look at urllib module:

(with Python 3.1, in Python 2, use urllib2.urlopen instead)
For retrieving cookies:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> d = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.co.uk")
>>> d.getheader('Set-Cookie')
'PREF=ID=a45c444aa509cd98:FF=0:TM=14.....'
```

And for sending, simply send a Cookie header with request. Like that:

```
r=urllib.request.Request("http://www.example.com/",headers={'Cookie':"session_id=1231245546"})
urllib.request.urlopen(r)
```

Edit:

The "http.cookie"("Cookie" for Python 2) may work for you better:

http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html

Comment: I am not getting the point "send a Set-Cookie header with request".Can you shaw me some example???

Comment: I'm not sure about Python 2, but on 3 you can shorten the last line to `d.info()['Set-Cookie']`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You can actually just use `d.getheader('Set-Cookie')` (tested in 3.4.1).

Comment: It works when you get "Set-cookie" header with 200 OK response. But if you get "Set-cookie" header in 302 "Found" response and Python follows the redirection (by default), then d.getheader(...) contains only headers from the last redirection and no "Set-cookie" header.

Answer (score 4):

You can use in Python 2.7

```
url="http://google.com"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
sock=urllib2.urlopen(request)
cookies=sock.info()['Set-Cookie']
content=sock.read()
sock.close()
print (cookies, content)
```

and when sending request back

```
def sendResponse(cookies): 
import urllib
request = urllib2.Request("http://google.com")
request.add_header("Cookie", cookies)
request.add_data(urllib.urlencode([('arg1','val1'),('arg1','val1')]))
opener=urllib2
opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
sock=opener.open(request)
content=sock.read()
sock.close()
print len(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Current answer is to use Requests module and the requests.Session object.

- Quick Start; http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content
- Sessions: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

```
    import requests
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
    r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
    print(r.text)
    # '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'

    print(s.cookies)
    # RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='sessioncookie', value='123456789', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='httpbin.org', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]
```

You may need to `pip install requests` or `pipenv install requests` first.