# How to log in over HTTPS via urllib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, urllib

I'm interested in using Python to retrieve a file that exists at an HTTPS url.

I have credentials for the site, and when I access it in my browser I'm able to download the file. How do I use those credentials in my Python script to do the same thing?

So far I have:

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https:// (some url with an XML file)')
html = response.read()

html.write('C:/Users/mhurley/Portable_Python/notebooks/XMLOut.xml')
```

This code works for non-secured pages, but (understandably) returns `401:Unauthorized` for the https address. I don't understand how urllib handles credentials, and the docs aren't as helpful as I'd like.

Comment: Are you saying that the same document is accessible over an unsecured connection but not on a secured connection?  As in, you can get to it by simply omitting the S before the ://

Comment: No, I'm saying that I know how to authenticate in the browser, but not in the script. In the browser, when I visit this page I'm presented with a login screen, or my account is still active from the last login. The script obviously requires credentials to authenticate, but I don't know how to do that authentication, and the docs for urllib aren't very clear.

Comment: The target server refuses requests to that url via HTTP (without the 's').

Comment: You need to do the login process from your script.  You'll probably POST the password and username in some format which you can see by inspecting the request in your browser's debug tools, store the cookies it sends back and send those cookies with each request.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606083/how-to-set-and-retrieve-cookie-in-http-header-in-python