# How to get the headers behind a login?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to create a bot to post message on a plateforme that requires login. I have done several reading online but I can't figure what the exactly the headers in a python requests stand for and how to get them ?

I have logged in manually to the website and post a message while inspecting the console network and succeed to copy the `POST` request as cURL than translated it to python language. Can someone explain me how the headers work and how to get them ?

The headers I copied from chrome console:

```
headers = {
    'cookie': 'JSESSIONID=523C2995451CCFC988FA097A85632B9F; csc=dom-use-prodwebapp-179.use.dom.carezen.net1560960000972; vc=9370b249-7a51-4291-a110-02332dffb2ed; n_vis=dom-use-prodwebapp-179.use.dom.carezen.net1560960000972; ROUTE2=d; _ga=GA1.2.1838448005.1560965623; _gid=GA1.2.1576009381.1560965623; mt.v=2.731501753.1560965623252; cto_lwid=44716745-0481-4223-9806-1c8201aa7991; mc_verify=EhAKEmJAM*EZDfeHJUUii1Eux5dvDMmMg3SVX4ULbB0Wo9KwYWs0EFCC67pzqF0bbSgcUFvmuwI11qh3FviCXA..; intl_src=en-us; mt.SFT-MT=1; __ssid=aae0f1f68f4613a358d86a8f63a09de; _RCRTX03=c43b78bb8e3a11e9b59929e665754f78129a93e4862141c5980f155f5ed6f58b; eps="my account login"; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9dGV3b3FwcER6amNITHQ4QUZiT1J4R0R2clg4MXZRQ18mbj0wVVZBVnZQU3dNS1lpY2JhYnBBV0N3Jm09NyZ0PUFBQUFBRjBMdjhr; mc=EhAKEmJAM%2BEZDfeHJUUii1Eux5dvDMmMg3SVX4ULbB0Wo9KwYWs0EFCC67pzqF0bbSgcUFvmuwI11qh3FviCXA%3D%3D; acs=L*UOHh2C8Xu*9PW02_*Ce6Oew*wRMnFB*b*Qsz7HT9Y.jx4xikhj-4e1e1h; ac=cqPM063k4O*PXdlekY6XiyEVjlI*XVG6roI0_mAVmyg.jx4xikhj-4e1e1h; _sp_id.6a17=bf7adf7e-f56d-4650-bbea-4b53734ea73a.1560965625.8.1561051105.1561010531.241ccbe8-ce5e-4bcf-9b3f-141aabf54e07; sc=R*5vUnwoNgwLU_TVziElnx8JKylwKx5omqzog5VpI9I.; n_tc=7416%7C2416%7C7467%7C7440%7C2127%7C2420%7C1871%7C2048%7C7300%7C7327%7C7375%7C7350%7C7261%7C1831%7C1311; lad="MTU2MTE0NTAzNTUyOQ=="; mt.c-lbx=20; bm_mi=F090A5625A4531D6A7A7BB9138A5C9D4~pdxKboVGxB7WtFWaP+KaJUI1bIO+hVzIOI6nj2028m79PR2Who3cXsYnvNJorc+JQ34bfEBpHtFlwWwDOfyaumh2UGIySCUgyBdw5hBDPArAHcnFCFp5cUDEzqlkAfhapH9eFeRxibJptHA3W5aYc3eNV/3tuOF1FXHkggdo2q+qCxPDTf0Gqeda9uIHN9N0TEABOokZ6+Jrx8hcdXb532A/ZA+bg/+279nh8M2gyGeocabQPdA8dxDZYYl4ASUcE3am4m9N5lEYPwS0knreOeVNkgD0lgcAeV7JapnNomVgOuSaqAnvzHtS3dJXQDfC; JSESSIONID=9D4B710D8379B4937BD45A70627E5298; utag_main=v_id:016b70cd30210012bce5d51584b403079001507100838$_sn:12$_ss:1$_st:1561158651946$ses_id:1561156851946%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; frsc=GDyIv*zSQoZ2l6K1jH9Xx1sPNSV3iBJvNL8amV_WBH5sVhc*Q1JpMMRXyfEI0alR-ZFKUaOP26pEkcsUJT0o7NA..; AKA_A2=A; _gat=1; RT=""; amplitude_id_49ee77491a2b775cf48ecf4a55ce04c5care.com=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6IjEwZmZlNzk5LWY1NmItNDk4Ny04ZjM2LWIwOGQzYmEzZTYyNFIiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI0MTM1MjIyOCIsIm9wdE91dCI6ZmFsc2UsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6MTU2MTE1Njg1MTU5MSwibGFzdEV2ZW50VGltZSI6MTU2MTE1OTI2NzQyNywiZXZlbnRJZCI6MjM5LCJpZGVudGlmeUlkIjo3Mywic2VxdWVuY2VOdW1iZXIiOjMxMn0=; ak_bmsc=2AFD7877A475A73646F14141938506F417D70A16856A00009A530D5DEEDD997A~plIddhcnR68Lv1XFm6VH5v+6Vi9hZSBjDY4l4AezuMSv5OC7k9RFzk+DI6ZhTMFpDp6CeyyW/uQhL2pmxZewAmktRfdMBvwfNyiNid/q5USAfuuW+rEBBA2w1VPtTXP3yCptKtS1uij3dnMb3Ua//MwDCbCZXCbGa0bi9xKhn4C2aGldt72vKtalrUzYXB6AvdvfcEtuoll7bZlfojQ5TcZcsq+BqsFULGshbI++j8ShCHMquc3rNXu3OJRHkU4adHJkT8HSv6INdESgDmMMsbTQ==',
    'owasptoken': 'WJUJ-IN87-VT3V-Z4BA-BXXG-VWWJ-9WM2-D44J',
    'origin': 'https://www. example.com',
    'x-care.com-apikey': 'cmtux62opFFZ8Aov8J0aoJ1zRonczZyqP60pTTURdfIx',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'x-care.com-visitid': '9370b249-7a51-4291-a110-02332dffb2ed',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'authority': 'www.example.com',
    'x-care.com-os': 'Desktop',
}
```

Comment: What status code and error message are you getting back from the platform?

Comment: Can you state more clearly what you have now, and what you need? The current wordings sound like "I have the headers, but I don't have the headers".

Comment: I succeeded to copy manually the header I will update it in my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have a lot of information in the header : how to get the cookies and the token with a python script ?

Comment: I have seen this post for cookies but the lib is not for python 3 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606083/how-to-set-and-retrieve-cookie-in-http-header-in-python

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the cookies and the token with a python script?

Given no details about your target site, I can share some general information about making HTTP requests in python.

You should spend some time to research and find necessary information by yourself, because the way this information is stored heavily depends on your target site.

- `cookie` is a special header. Server sets a cookie for client by sending `Set-Cookie` header in its response headers. Browser stores all these cookies for this particular domain in form of key-value pairs, which you can obviously observe in your browser's settings. When you perform subsequent HTTP requests (auth for example), browser sends all cookies for this domain in `cookie` header.
- `owasptoken` and all others are just ordinary HTTP headers. Their respective values can be either hardcoded in `js` code of the page, or received via ajax requests performed by `js`. Things like `user-agent` are provided by your browser. Again, this is a subject for a research.

So to obtain [cookies with requests lib](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) you should probably call a `GET` on your target page and save a cookie from response:

```py
import requests  # pip3 install requests

url = "http://www......."  # probably login page
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0......."})
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.cookies)
else:  # request failed
    print(r.status_code, r.text)
```

It's easier to do that in a single `requests` [session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) since it will save its state between HTTP requests and [send cookies automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737874/2315573) like your browser.

Comment: thank you @Ivan for your comment? Just one type: it is `r.cookies`
I succeed to get the cookies how can I get the `owasptoken` after login ?

Comment: If you need to get `owasptoken` **after** login, you can look for it in `r.headers` after you made a request.